# How to get Login object from DataSource or Connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, database-connection

I want to create a `DatabaseSession` through `Project.createDatabaseSession()`. In order to do is, I need to set `Project.SetLogin(Login login)`.

The problem is I'm getting my `datasource` through spring bean. In other words I already have Connection and `DataSource`. 
All I need to do is, somehow extract `Login` object out of this connection.

Is it possible to do is or is there a way round?

Comment: If you already have what you need through Spring, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Also, we have no idea what a `Login` object is, but I assume it's your class. You don't need to create a database session manually. Let Spring handle those for you.

Comment: Login is from persistence.sessions. Is is possible to get Project object out of this connection maybe?

Comment: `Connection` wraps a database connection. `DataSource` provides a way to retrieve `Connection` objects (with possible pooling or other things depending on the implementation of the `DataSource`). You're not going to get anything else out of those, but maybe your `Project` can wrap a `Connection` or (preferably) `DataSource`?